# Keeping secrets

Tags: dnd-5e, investigation

I'm running a game where the characters are unraveling a group of assassins that are hunting down magic users. I was looking for some realistic ways to dole out enough information to keep the PCs going without just giving them the location of the big bad. With interrogation, both magical and mundane I don't know how to make it make sense that they can't get all the information.

So far I've had some people just not know and some have a magic version of the cyanide tooth but I'd love some other options if you could think of any.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.se! Please take a look at the [tour]; it's a useful introduction to the site. It seems like this is an invitation to brainstorm ideas. On this site [questions must have specific answers](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) rather than requesting general input. [Your question might be better suited to a traditional forum](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go), as you'll get more helpful feedback on a site intended for open-ended discussion.